# Contraction Mapping Principle for System of Equations

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Show that the system of equations:

$x_1 = \frac{1}{4}x_1 - \frac{1}{4}x_2 + \frac{2}{15}x_3 +3 $

$x_2 = \frac{1}{4}x_1 + \frac{1}{5}x_2 + \frac{1}{2}x_3 -1 $

$x_3 = -\frac{1}{4}x_1 + \frac{1}{3}x_2 - \frac{1}{3}x_3 +2$

has a unique solution, using the contraction mapping principle.

I approached the question by attempting to choose a clever norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since the sum of the coefficients for each coordinate is less than 1, I chose the norm to be the 1-norm. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: What's your operator? And from what space into what space? And why is it a contraction? And if it is a contraction, how does the CMP get you to a unique solution to the system? Lots of details to discuss...

Comment: Hmmm, define $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ where each space is under the 1 norm. Can I define $\Phi(x_n) = x_{n+1}$?

Comment: Note that if you endow $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1$ norm, it's the maximum of the absolute values of the coefficients in each row that is relevant, and the easy estimate of the operator norm gives the sum of these maxima, which is $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} > 1$. More careful analysis of the matrix may push the operator norm below $1$, I haven't checked. But a different norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$, where the maximum of the sums of the absolute values of the coefficients in each row is pertinent exists.

Comment: @DanielFischer I believe $|| \cdot ||_{\infty}$ is the maximum of the absolute values of the coefficients in each row.

Comment: @JohnD can you provide more insight for the approach to the problem?